# Robot Framework: Cannot close popup window

Tags: robotframework

With `Open Browser` I open Chrome and basic "cookie" popup window pops up:[image]

But I can't close this (for some reason robot cannot find that button even tho I put some sleep before trying. Do I need to change focus to this popup window somehow?

Code:

```
*** Keywords ***
Open oikotie
    Open Browser  ${OIKOTIE_LOGIN_DOMAIN}  ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

    # Popup window
    Sleep  5s
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  xpath://* 
    [@id="notice"]/div[5]/button[2]
    Click Button  xpath://* 
    [@id="notice"]/div[5]/button[2]
```

Error:
Open and login to oikotie
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59927/devtools/browser/645040dd-bf8c-4252-9623-5f14c7bb8610
[19800:23684:0803/170959.082:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:09:59.081] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Open and login to oikotie                                             | FAIL |
Element 'xpath://*[@id="notice"]/div[5]/button[2]' not visible after 5 seconds.

Comment: Check if that button is not inside a iFrame, if it is you need to switch to the iFrame before being able to access that button

Comment: @Antti - that popup is inside iframe .. `Select Frame` before using any selectors that are unique to that iframe and then you need to select the top frame afterwards ..